# layout problem floating issues safari and firefox

Tags: css, firefox, safari, stylesheet

can someone look at this site for me I have a serious problem with the sub pages content div going over to the right bar this issue the site renders fine in all other browsers except safari firefox and iphone

www.firstavenuedesign.co.uk/demo

http://www.firstavenuedesign.co.uk/demo/offers.aspx

if u look at the above page in ie it will display fine and chrome any ideas anyone

Comment: Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things work. Notice how you say it works in IE but nothing else? IE is the worst browser on the planet. Get it working in a modern browser first. Then check incompetent IE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the problem you are having relates to your parent DIV 'collapsing' on your floated child elements.

The following article explains how to resolve this issue (in the Collapsing section) a long with other approaches for laying out floating elements:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Answer (score 0):

Validate your html and css for those lists of significant errors. Then get this working in a modern browser before seeing how IE screws things up. The other browsers are showing what you wrote. IE makes things up as it goes along. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right.

Also, you have space before the doctype. Some versions of IE go into quirks mode in that situation.